# sqLite - GROUP BY in modified columns with CAST

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

I'm working on an Android SQLite (testing with a Galaxy s2)
I can not solve this problem

I have a database like this:

```
COORDINATES
id latitude   longitude
1  37.996163  -116.644592
2  37.996163  -116.644592
3  37.957507  -116.67467
4  36.370157  -91.156311
```

I run the query:

```
select CAST((latitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lat, CAST((longitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lon from coordinates group by lat,lon
```

I expect:

```
lat  lon
379  -1166
363  -911
```

instead I get:

```
lat  lon
379  -1166
379  -1166
363  -911
```

perform the "group by" on values ​​not modified by CAST
I'm doing something wrong? the same query on a mysql works perfectly.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite does not have `UNSIGNED` datatype and casting to it doesn't really do anything. The values are floating point until you call e.g. `Cursor` `getInt()` to convert them to integer.

Cast to e.g. `INTEGER` instead:

```
sqlite> create table coordinates(id integer primary key, latitude, longitude);
sqlite> insert into coordinates values(1,37.996163,-116.644592),(2,37.996163,-116.644592),(3,37.957507,-116.67467),(4,36.370157,-91.156311);
sqlite> .head on
sqlite> select CAST((latitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lat, CAST((longitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lon from coordinates group by lat,lon;
lat|lon
363.70157|-911.56311
379.57507|-1166.7467
379.96163|-1166.44592
sqlite> select CAST((latitude*10) AS INTEGER) AS lat, CAST((longitude*10) AS INTEGER) AS lon from coordinates group by lat,lon;
lat|lon
363|-911
379|-1166
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I am not sure this will work or not but I know that change in select clause does not work in where, group...so try this

```
select CAST((latitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lat, CAST((longitude*10) AS UNSIGNED) AS lon
from coordinates 
group by CAST((latitude*10) AS UNSIGNED), CAST((longitude*10) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: setting "integer" instead of "unsigned" works well.

 i could use your advice in this way:

select MAX(id) from coordinates group by CAST((latitude*10) AS INTEGER), CAST((longitude*10) AS INTEGER)